# Interactive data visualization in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, visualization, data-visualization

Can anyone please recommend some javascript/jquery data visualization libraries that matches the following criteria:

```
"
    -takes the entire dataset in one go in some reasonable format (i.e. as a JSON object) as input
    -is interactive:
       -user can specify the chart format (bar chart, scatterplot, pie chart, etc.)
       -user can specify the data range and which columns of a data set are to be plotted
    -is relatively efficient, and doesn't have too much of a memory footprint
    -can generate an image file from the visualization
    -produces attractive visualizations
    -is free to use, with no limitations
"
```

Thank you!

Comment: yes, try D3: http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 1):

We are using recline.js for a long time and it is based on backbone.js as MVVC framework and you can use also d3.js as view framework.

There are a lot of forks on Github that add cool graphs and add-ons.

Comment: At a glance, looks cool - will give it a more thorough look. Thanks!